# =GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL";"eps";TODAY(); today()-60)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I've found nice function =GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL";"price";TODAY(); today()-60) that gives stock prices for defined date range - it works fine.
I was trying to use it to get EPS or PE data. Is that possible to get EPS historical data using googlefinance() (I was trying with =GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL";"eps";TODAY(); today()-60) but it is not working) or we can get only current EPS with =GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL;"eps")
Will appreciate your support on this.

KG

Answer (score 1):

EPS is not supported, only:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL"; "all"; TODAY(); TODAY()-60)
```

Answer (score 0):

EPS data is not supported.

However the price is adjusted for bonus, stocksplit ESOPS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use following, A3 is the cell with tricker name:

=GOOGLEFINANCE(A3,"eps")

In your case it is like this:

=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "eps")

Problem is that eps is only support teal-time data, so we can't fill any data with that.